# resizing a div with browser size? (Not an easy question)

Tags: css, browser, html, resize

here is my html

```
<div id="sidetop"><div>
<div id="sidemiddle"><div>
<div id="sidebottom"></div>
<span class="logotext">wegbweifgnqweilgnqwleing</span>
```

and my css

```
body {
color: #333333;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sidetop {
    background: url(images/top.png);
    top:0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 59px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

#sidebottom {
    background: url(images/bottom.png);
    bottom:0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 59px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

#sidemiddle {
    background: #000;
    top: 59px;
    bottom: 59px;
    height: 86.3%;
    width: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
}

.logotext {
    display: block;
    width: 730px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-size:35px;
    letter-spacing:0.2em;
    margin-top:325px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-347px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and it ends up like this

[image]

but the values that ive used to position the elements only work with my specific browser size. How can I get #sidemiddle to resize to fill the gap between the top.png and the bottom.png regardless of the browser size? Also can I centre the text so that it stays in the middle of the shape regardless of browser size? Thanks

Comment: You're right, this isn't an easy question. I would personally have just used JavaScript for this.

Comment: I am no good at javascript. Can you link me to something that might do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like someone has [figured out how to do this](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) without JavaScript. It's really one huge hack, so it probably has some kinks, but here's the example code that was used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And [here](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html) is the result. The article includes a more valid (non-hacky) way of doing it, but it doesn't work in IE 7.

Basically, the point is to use the `display: table` and `vertical-align: middle` properties on standards-compliant browsers, and resort to `position` hacks on IE. The properties with the `#` symbol before them can only be read by Internet Explorer.